# How to log in in Sandbox Paypal Account?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Paypal have recently changed their user interface in developers.paypal and as such, I couldn't find out the place from where I can log in to my old *SANDBOX* account.

In the new developer.paypal.com, on the *Application* tab, I selected the *sandbox* account,

In the following link,

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

I get a button "*login with paypal*". But when I try to login, it displays a message "*Invalid email*" even though my email and password are totally correct.

Comment: For me the problem was that PayPal created different passwords for my sandbox accounts than for my real account, and I tried to log in using the password for my real account. To see the passwords for your sandbox accounts, go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/, click on an account in the list, then click change password and enter a password that you know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The new developer accounts require that you first log in using a live PayPal account email address and password. Once you log in you can recover your test accounts by following the steps below.

- Log into https://developer.paypal.com
- Click Applications
- Click Sandbox accounts
- Click "Import data"
- Enter your email address and password for the old developer account.

Since you've had access to the legacy developer account you'll also need to delete your cookies and cache. Strangely enough, if you don't there will be several issues with logging into the account or accessing the test accounts. This will also resolve the invalid email error.

Let me know if you have any issues after this.

Comment: what if i dont have a live paypal account..... i never had live paypal account........ i just have sandbox account always..

Comment: This was one of the additions of the beta developer account. If you do not have a PayPal account you can click Sign Up on the Developer website and add minimal information to create an account. Currently it's required to log in to developer.paypal.com.

Comment: One of the things Paypal developer needs when creating an account is to tie in a credit card. Is there a way to skip this? We just want to create sandbox and kick the tires first before committing anything. It's just downright bad design.

Answer (score 18):

Go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com , then key in your account which create automatically when you register via https://developer.paypal.com

Answer (score 7):

You can login here for paypal's sandbox environment https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/home

Answer (score 0):

If you've never had a legacy account you can access it from the developer profile.

1. go to developer.paypal.com
2. Click Applications
3. Choose Sandbox Accounts
4. Under 'Account Details' you'll see a Profile tab
5. the email and password are your sandbox profile, you may have to choose a password.